# Do we need a Trump-tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

we have [212 questions containing the keyword Trump](https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq%20trump), many of them focussing if things he did or ordered are legal.

That's more than our [Treelaw questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treelaw), so a trump category of questions might be worth an investment.

On the other hand, a category like that would require a similar tag for questions on other presidents actions and their legal ramifications, for example, one might need to sift through [Nixon (17)](https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq%20nixon), [Obama (33)](https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq%20obama) & [Clinton (20)](https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq%20Clinton)

Comment: [tag:treelaw] seems totally unnecessary, both of those questions are covered by topics around access, trespass, "the right to a good view" and similar.

Comment: @Nij r/Treelaw ?

Comment: I presume you're mention r/ for a reason, but this being SE (that is, not Reddit) you'll need to make its relevance more explicit.

Comment: @Nij it's a reference to the fact that cutting down trees in the neighbor's yard can be so expensive, it costs you the house.

Comment: The question demonstrates how easy it is for a user to find Q&A containing a particular name using the built-in search function.  The same is not true of all subject tags.

Comment: Can anyone be an expert on "Trump"?

Comment: Further discussion at Meta question: [Should the newly created "trump" tag be deleted or be merged with the "president" tag?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1461/35069)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest steering clear of tags for natural persons, though there's nothing stopping us from creating them. Perhaps the others could be merged into [president](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president).

Comment: No, they should not be merged into [tag:president]. If anything, a new [Tag:President-united-states].

Comment: @Nij That works.

Comment: @Nij If you're creating a tag like that, shouldn't it be president-of-the-united-states? That's the formal title, which is why the acronym for the position is POTUS.

Comment: Meh, we don't even have [tag:prime-minister] so I'm not overly concerned about having a [tag:president-murka] created either. @nick012000

Comment: @Nij: the current tag usage guidelines say to tag with "president" and with a country tag, i.e. "united-states".

Comment: And guidelines can't be edited to include more relevant information when new tags are created? I don't see what useful point your comment makes.

Comment: Note that the [tag length limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/243091) is 35 (not 25 as I wrote in an earlier wrong comment, now deleted), so @nick012000 's proposal fits.

Answer (score 3):

**There are guidelines on this**

This is what tags are for: https://law.stackexchange.com/help/tagging

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

Bear in mind:

> As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible, and new users are not allowed to create new tags. Even if you have sufficient reputation, you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

So, is Trump a topic worthy of a tag? If he is, what about Washington, Putin, Erdoğan, Hitler?

I wouldn't. But you have the privilege to create tags so if in your judgement it should exist, go ahead and create it.

Answer (score 1):

> Do we need a Trump-tag?

No. The sheer number of questions a public figure elicits should not be a factor for or against creating a tag.

Creating tags for specific individuals would make sense only in instances of renown jurists such as [Holmes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Wendell_Holmes_Jr.), [Kelsen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Kelsen), or thinkers and theoreticians whose impact on law theory & development is significant. Trump is a highly controversial person, but that does not render him a reference for understanding or developing any topics of law.