# Should the newly created [trump] tag be deleted or be merged with the [president] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[This question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/81178/35069) created the [trump](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trump) tag which, in line with the consensus of opinion with [this Meta question](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1151/35069), I have exchanged for [president](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president) which has the [tag info](https://law.stackexchange.com/tags/president/info):

> For questions regarding heads of state with the title "President." Should be used with a jurisdiction tag to indicate which country the question is about.

Should [trump](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trump) be deleted or merged as a synonym of [president](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president)?

Comment: It currently seems this does not have the level of consensus that it may have appeared to have 2 days ago. I ask that @feetwet delete the prematurely created synonym relationship until a clearer consensus is achieved here.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: The older meta discussion linked in Trish's answer seems like adequate support.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## [It was decided then that we don't need it.](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1151/do-we-need-a-trump-tag?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Keep it that way. We don't need a clutter of dozens of president tags, and it wouldn't advance the tagging system.

A synonym would prevent creation in the future, so easy way.

Comment: So merge or delete?

Comment: @Rick synonym to perma-burninate

Answer (score 2):

Former President Trump had a good many legal issues related to his actions and to actions against him that are unique, both in volume and in nature. I think this tag is potentially useful.