# Should we merge the us-president and potus tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

It looks like I've created both [us-president](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-president) and [potus](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potus). I'm not sure why I did that; should we merge them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Do not merge with "President"

I favor merging the tags [potus](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potus) and [us-president](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-president), but I strongly oppose merging either with  [president](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president). We get enough questions specifically about the role, powers and duties of the US President specifically that a separate tag is justified. The tag [president](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president) is for officials having that title in any country, and should so remain.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that both [potus](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potus) and [us-president](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-president) tags are merged with the extant [president](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president) tag accompanied by the relevant [jurisdiction](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jurisdiction) tag

[president](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president) has, at the time of writing, 110 questions, been active for over 6 years, and has the following user guidance:

> For questions regarding heads of state with the title "President." Should be used with a jurisdiction tag to indicate which country the question is about.

Also related: [Should the newly created [trump] tag be deleted or be merged with the [president] tag?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1461/35069)

And, to a lesser degree, here: [Do we need a Trump-tag?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1151/35069)